# How to find unique element of a subset of a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I wanna find all elements of a sublist of a nested list that are not in none other sublist.

input: suppose I wanna find unique elements of `H[0]`

```
H=[['A','B'],['C','D'],['A','D','J']]
```

Output:

```
result=['B']    # 'B' is not in ['C','D']or ['A','D','J']
```

Here is my try:

```
for i in H[0]:
    if all(i not in H[j] and j!=0 for j in range(2)):
        print(i)
```

But nothing is printed. where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for `j != 0` in the `all()` statement means that every i will fail when j is 0. To exclude certain values from an `all()` check, put your conditional after the generator expression:

```py
for i in H[0]:
    if all(i not in H[j] for j in range(len(H)) if j != 0):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Prefer this:  for x in H[0]:  if all(x not in H[i] for i in `range(1, len(H)))`:   print(x)`

Comment: @DanielHao For j =0, that is cleaner. However, since the question was about any sublist, I feel that the post-conditional is cleaner than the two ranges/concatenation you would need for j > 0

Comment: why I got -1 vote? now I can not ask a new question! what was wrong in my question really?

Comment: @shere I'm not sure who downvoted you, but it might be because you didn't go into depth about solutions you had tried or explored. See, for example, [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)